# Slack Bot | Get datepicker value

Tags: python, slack, slack-api

I'm trying to create my first slack bot with python.
I need your help to explain how I can get the value of the datepicker.
This is my code :

```
import os 
from slack import WebClient
from slack.errors import SlackApiError
import time

client = WebClient(token=os.environ['SLACK_KEY'])

message = "Hey ! Pourrais-tu saisir la date de tes congés ce mois-ci ?"
attachments = [{
    "blocks": [
        {
            "type": "actions",
            "elements": [
                {
                    "type": "datepicker",
                    "initial_date": "1990-04-28",
                    "placeholder": {
                        "type": "plain_text",
                        "text": "Select a date",
                    }
                },
                {
                    "type": "datepicker",
                    "initial_date": "1990-04-28",
                    "placeholder": {
                        "type": "plain_text",
                        "text": "Select a date",
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}]


def list_users():
    users_call = client.api_call("users.list")
    if users_call.get('ok'):
        return users_call['members']
    return None

def send_message(userid):
    response = client.chat_postMessage(channel=userid, text=message, username='groupadamin', attachments=attachments)
    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    users = list_users()
    if users:
        for u in users:
            send_message(u['id'])
        print("Success!")
```

My bot sends a private message to all users of the slack. I want to get every one of their answers of the datepicker.

If you want more details, ask me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, you need to be **listening to the action**.
When the use clicks the datetimepicker, a so-called `interaction-payload` will be sent to your python slackbot.
That payload is documented here https://api.slack.com/reference/interaction-payloads/block-actions ; you can see you can get the picked date's value by accessing `actions.value`.

In particular for your use case, given your code sample, it seems you've just built a script that can send messages. This will not allow you to listen to actions. You need rather a python service (an API) that can send as well as receive messages.
For this, I suggest having a look at [`bolt`](https://slack.dev/bolt-python/tutorial/getting-started) which is a slack maintained library that will take care of a lot of the heavy lifting for you. Specifically, regarding actions you can check https://slack.dev/bolt-python/concepts#action-listening

Comment: Hi there, thanks for this answer, seems to be surprisingly little info on Slack interaction components on Stack Overflow. But it seems like you can't access `actions.value` directly for the multi select component. You need to access the body (only suggested in docs), and then the `selected_options` dict to get user input is extremely nested within body. Is there a better way?

Comment: Ah my bad, the technical docs are not that expressive, so disregard my comment above. Actually you need to specify the `action` argument as an alias for "body" payload and this gives you a shortcut so you don't need to go so many levels deep to access selected_options. But you can't just do `actions.value` in Python.